# Generic.xaml xaml compilation gives error WMC0610 (XBF generation error code 0x3e9) on control style

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10

Getting the following error when compiling XAML in a library:

> Themes\Generic.xaml(35,12): XamlCompiler error WMC0610: XBF generation
>   error code 0x03e9.

The XAML code  it's failing on (line 35) is:

```
<Style TargetType="annotations:CanvasAnnotationItem" xmlns:annotations="using:ACME.Controls.CanvasAnnotation">
```

No extra info to help with the error.

Answer (score 10):

For some reason, the XAML compiler does not know how to handle that local namespace (the one defined directly on the style). Moving it up to the top of the file solves the issue:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:annotations="using:ACME.Controls.CanvasAnnotation"
    xmlns:local="using:ACME.Controls">
```

And in the element itself:

```
<Style TargetType="annotations:CanvasAnnotationItem">
```

Comment: For posterity, I had to remove a property it wasn't finding (although it compiled on a different computer).  I was hoping the Xaml designer would have gotten friendlier in the last 10 years but alas, it has not. :p